# Pi model in Circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz, circuits, tikz-circuit-lib

Can anyone draw the Pi-model like the image below using `circuitikz`?

[image: picture of circuit]

Comment: What you have able to do yourself? [__MWE__](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl) start with `\documentclass{..` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Should it be so ugly? Jokes apart, the tutorials in the circuitikz manual should get you started in minutes. Start you circuit, and if you got stuck post your partial result here and we'll help. Like it is now, it seems a "I can't be bothered to learn, please do it for me" question...

Comment: To answer your question, yes, anyone can draw it  All it takes is time and effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I couldn't read some of the labels so I've just guessed what they say.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=20]{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % Grounds
        \node[ground] (ground1) at (0, 0) {};
        \node[ground] (ground2) at (4, 0) {};
        
        % Left hand side
        \draw (ground1) to[short, *-] ($(ground1) + (-1, 0)$) to[C=\(C_{\mathrm{sub}}\)] ($(ground1) + (-1, 2)$);
        \draw (ground1) -- ($(ground1) + (1, 0)$) to[R=\(R_{\mathrm{sub}}\)] ($(ground1) + (1, 2)$) -- ($(ground1) + (-1, 2)$);
        \draw ($(ground1) + (0, 2)$) to[C=\(C_{\mathrm{ox}}\), *-] ($(ground1) + (0, 4)$);
        
        % Right hand side
        \draw (ground2) to[short, *-] ($(ground2) + (-1, 0)$) to[C=\(C_{\mathrm{sub}}\)] ($(ground2) + (-1, 2)$);
        \draw (ground2) -- ($(ground2) + (1, 0)$) to[R=\(R_{\mathrm{sub}}\)] ($(ground2) + (1, 2)$) -- ($(ground2) + (-1, 2)$);
        \draw ($(ground2) + (0, 2)$) to[C=\(C_{\mathrm{ox}}\), *-] ($(ground2) + (0, 4)$);
        
        % Horizontal components
        \draw ($(ground1) + (-1, 4)$) to[short, o-] ($(ground1) + (0, 4)$) to[american inductor, L=\(L_{\mathrm{s}}\)] ($(ground1) + (2, 4)$) to[R=\(R_{\mathrm{s}}\)] ($(ground2) + (0, 4)$) to[short, -o] ($(ground2) + (1, 4)$);
        \draw ($(ground1) + (0, 4)$) to[short, *-] ($(ground1) + (0, 5)$);
        \draw ($(ground2) + (0, 4)$) to[short, *-] ($(ground2) + (0, 5)$);
        \draw ($(ground1) + (0, 5)$) to[C=\(C_{\mathrm{p}}\)] ($(ground2) + (0, 5)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!